# How to deploy JHipster v8+ on GCP without JHipster gae?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, deployment, jhipster

I used JHipster `gae` to deploy JHipster on GCP, as is explained [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/gcp/), but [version 8](https://www.jhipster.tech/2023/10/14/jhipster-release-8.0.0-rc.1.html) has dropped unmaintained deployment sub-generators (#23422):

1. aws
2. azure-app-service
3. azure-spring-cloud
4. cloudfoundry
5. gae
6. openshift

Are there any instructions to follow when deploying an app?

Thanks